# Formas de Popular ListView com Retrofit 2

Tags: android, listview, retrofit

Apesar de já existir uma pergunta semelhante, não esclareceu minha dúvida, meu problema é o seguinte, o código abaixo é do onResponse do Retrofit, estou começando agora em Java, gostaria de jogar o resultado do response.body no listView, eu consegui fazendo um for no código  stringList.add(countryList.get(i).getNome())) porem gostaria de saber se não teria uma maneira melhor de se fazer, vi alguns exemplos usando o Course, porem minhas requisições vão retornar cerca de 1400 linhas então não sei se usando for pode comprometer o desempenho, pensei se não poderia ter outra maneira mais elegante de se fazer, no codigo abaixo eu tentei jogar a Lista com o response.body() direto no ArrayAdapter, so que dessa forma o app retorna os dados assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
public void onResponse(Call < List < Funcionarios >> call, Response < List < Funcionarios >> response) {
  try {

    List < String > stringList = new ArrayList < > ();
    ListView lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    TextView qtdtotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    List < Funcionarios > countryList = response.body();

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter < > (getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, countryList);
     

lista.setAdapter(adapter)

} catch (Exception e) {
  Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

```js
@GET("/webservice/webservice.php")
Call < List < Funcionarios >> getFunc(@Query("empresa") String empresa);
```

```js
public class Funcionarios{
    @SerializedName("NOME")
    private String nome;
    @SerializedName("MAT")
    private int matricula;
    @SerializedName("EMP")
    private int empresa;

    private List<Funcionarios> lsfunc = null;
    public List<Funcionarios> getFunc() {
        return lsfunc;
    }

    public void setFunc(List<Funcionarios> posts) {
        this.lsfunc = posts;
    }

    public int getMatricula() {return matricula ; }

    public int getEmpresa() {
        return empresa ;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setMatricula(){
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }
    public void setNome(){
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public void setEmpresa(){
        this.empresa = empresa;
    }

}
```

Comment: O ideal então seria trabalhar com paginação. Em vez de retornar todos os resultados de uma vez, fazer uma requisição limitando a quantidade de itens. Ai na medida que vai rolando o scroll, você vai fazendo uma nova requisição com mais um "pacote" de itens.

Comment: Entao, a lista no meu caso é pra melhorar a interação, pois penso em implementar um filtro que mostre o resultado na lista...porem no caso eu posso nao fazer ela, pois no caso esses dados recebidos vao ser inseridos no sqlite, so que com a lista ficaria melhor pra conferir se o filtro correu bem.

Comment: Coloquei uma resposta explicando por cima uma ideia de como poderia ser feito. =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Resolvendo o problema das "1400 linhas":

O ideal seria trabalhar com paginação. Em vez de retornar todos os resultados de uma vez, fazer uma requisição limitando a quantidade de itens. Na medida que vai rolando o `scroll`, você vai fazendo uma nova requisição com mais um "pacote" de itens.

Veja abaixo um exemplo passando o limite e a página como parâmetro. O `limit` representa a quantidade de itens que quer que retorne a cada requisição. O `page` representa qual página você quer mostrar.

```
@GET("/webservice/webservice.php)
Call <List<Funcionarios>> getFunc(
    @Query("empresa") String empresa,
    @Query("limit") int limit,
    @Query("page") int page,
    );
```

Sendo assim, você precisa fazer uma alteração no seu webservice.php para reconhecer os parâmetros.

Veja abaixo um exemplo de como precisa passar na sua `query`:

```
SELECT nome, matricula, empresa FROM tblEmpresas LIMIT 0,10
```

Esta `query` acima, retornará 10 itens da primeira página. Veja abaixo mais 10 itens da segunda página.

```
 SELECT nome, matricula, empresa FROM tblEmpresas LIMIT 1,10
```

Sendo assim, você você usa as váriaveis recebidas `$_GET['limit']` e `$_GET['page']`:

```
 SELECT nome, matricula, empresa FROM tblEmpresas LIMIT $_GET['page'].','.$_GET['limit']
```

Este é só um exemplo por cima baseado no que pretende fazer.

#### Resolvendo da impressão do objeto:

O segundo problema é que você está imprimir um objeto na lista e não uma única *string*. Para resolver  você não pode inserir `response.body()` diretamente ao `countryList`. Você tem que usar algo do tipo:

```
List <Funcionarios> countryList = response.body().getFunc();
```

E tem uma outra coisa, como é uma lista de objetos, você teria que criar um `Adapter` customizado. Veja [aqui um exemplo](https://paulacr.net/2015/05/18/criando-uma-lista-customizada/) de como [criar uma lista customizada](https://paulacr.net/2015/05/18/criando-uma-lista-customizada/):

Comment: acklay vou ler a respeito depois passo o resultado, Muito Obrigado pelas informações.

Comment: acklay, pelo que vi e li, acho que vou ficar com o for mesmo, através das informações que você me passou acho que é a forma mais simples de se fazer, qualquer coisa se o desempenho ficar comprometido eu invista na paginação, porem como o app só ira trabalhar na intranet...talvez de certo...Muito Obrigado!

Comment: @DungaCardoso disponha! Qualquer coisa dê um toque aqui que tentaremos resolver. Nos meus apps, sempre coloco paginação, pois deixa a aplicação fluindo melhor. Quando é o caso de ter que baixar tudo de uma vez, para mostrar em um sqlite mais tarde, crio um progressbar logo no inicio para buscar todos os dados necessários. Sendo assim, o usuário é obrigado a esperar alguns segundinhos para interagir com a aplicação. Um conselho que te dou que vai te ajudar, é usar RecyclerView e não ListView. O RecyclerView é mais flexivel. Boa sorte.

Comment: Um rapaz que esta me ajudando, já que realmente estou engatinhando ainda me recomendou usar RecyclerView, só que no momento estou recorrendo a simplicidade, ainda tenho dificuldades com o básico da linguagem, porém entre NullPointer, Exceptions...eu vou aprendendo kkkk